# Windows phone calendar month view as datepicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datepicker

Is it possible to use the calendar month view as datepicker? Make a custom control?

Comment: Yes, you could use the `click event` on each calender-item to set the output.

Comment: ok. How do I get the calendar view to show? And is it also possible to make so that I only can select the date of the day and back.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a XAML page with calender view and can pass the selected date in the parameters along with the previous XAML page from where you landed on the calender view page.

For example, you have a xaml page - **MainPage.xaml** with button "**Select Date**". On `Tap/Click event` of the button use the following code:

```
private void selectDate_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/dateView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

On **dateView.xaml** page place your calender view and on calender item click event do the following:

```
private void calenderItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   var selectedDate = /*calender's selected item*/;
   var lastPage = NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault();
   string pageName = lastPage.ToString();
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(pageName+"?date="+selectedDate, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Then again on **MainPage.xaml** you could do the following:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(Microsoft.Phone.Navigation.PhoneNavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
    String date = NavigationContext.QueryString["date"]; 
}
```

Comment: You say "On dateView.xaml page place your calender view" what do you mean?